# read passport variable in ng-view

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

Hi i have this little problem

I have this structure of template :

```
<div id="navbar">..... Connected as #{user.username} </div>
<div id="main>
   <div id="ng-view"> Here go my partial templates </div>
</div>
```

Now i want to display my passport variable in my partial template profile.jade, which goes into the ng-view div

```
<h3>Profile of #{user.username}</h3>
```

Unfortunately , the user.username variable from passport, which i get from express, is well displayed in my navbar but not in the ng-view, it is empty.

Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it gets overwritten in the scope of the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jade templates are parsed by the server, whereas angular are parsed by the client.

If you're loading the client-side template after the initial render, then it's not going to pick up the variable.

There are a couple ways to go about this, you could add the user object to a global variable on initial load, then get it with your angular application.

```
head
    script.
        var app = {};
        app.user = JSON.parse(!{JSON.stringify(user)});
```

Then somewhere down the line,

```
$scope.user = app.user;
```

Or you can setup some REST routes to get the user's session using AJAX in angular.

You could also pre-render your templates using jade.

Comment: sorry for the delay. i have a problem at the line app.user = json.. : referenceError : id is not defined do you have any clue on that ? inspecting the browser i can see the object in the html ( with token , username and  stuff ) but with &quot; instead of real quotes cant tell if it is a problem or not ..

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Looks like `#{}` escapes it, so use `!{}` instead. I'll change the answer.